# Should I autoload everything, and how do I autoload a namespace in different directories

Tags: php, symfony, autoload

Let's say my application has models, views and controllers. How can I autoload many directories for a specific namespace?

```
require_once __DIR__.'/lib/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespace('Test', __DIR__ . '/lib');
$loader->register();
```

Let's say that I also have files in like /application that (model, controller) Would I need to have YET another Test folder and then containing the Application, Model.

Like this;

```
Root.
Application
  Test
    Model
    Application
lib
  Test
   Other folders.
```

Or is it POSSIBLE to get rid of the "Test" (namespace folder)?

Comment: Why don't you want the `Test/`-folder?

Comment: Personally I think it doesn't make any sense having the namespace directory in the application folder; but yet again maybe controllers, models (MVC) shouldn't be autoloaded by a Symfony ClassLoader(?)

Comment: I makes "a little sense", because then the folder structure directly reflects the class structure and you don't need to look into the files to know, which classes are inside. On the other side, it doesn't make sense (at least in my eyes ;)) to get rid of the folder just "because". // I autoload everything :) Exactly one `require` and nothing more. However, I built my tools and sites on top of composer in the meantime, what makes everything even a little bit easier.